# creating generic enum wrapper for validations

Tags: java, generics, types, enums, instance

Disclaimer: not very strong with generics.

```
enum WeekDays {
   SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY;
}
enum Months {
   JANUARY, FEBRAURY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER;
}
enum Directions {
   East, West, North, South, Up, Down
}
```

Let's say I have above enums and there is a service which sends me random Strings.

I need to verify if the targeted String response is a valid enum value or not.

I was thinking of coding of something on lines as below:

```
static <T> boolean isValidEnum(String value, T enumClass ){
   try {
       enumClass.valueOf(value);
       return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
   return false;
}
```

The call would be like:

```
isValidEnum("TUESDAY", WeekDays)
```

but line `enumClass.valueOf(value);` is not happy about my function.

Any pointers is appreciated! TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite it to this:

```java
static <T extends Enum<T>> boolean isValidEnum(String value, Class<T> enumClass ){
    try {
        Enum.valueOf(enumClass, value);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

and

```java
isValidEnum("TUESDAY", WeekDays.class)
```

Comment: simple and elegant, missed the `Enum` utility completely!

Comment: Simple, but not elegant: it throws an exception every time the value is not valid

Comment: @AndreaLigios: IMHO, exceptions if raised consciously are better sometimes than taking the long path of iteration but then again, individual opinion varies!

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate the Enum values and check if there is a match with the value passed:

With **Java 8** and newer versions:

```
static <T> boolean isValidEnum(String value, T enumClass ){
    return Arrays.stream(((Class) enumClass).getEnumConstants())
            .anyMatch(v -> v.toString().equals(value));
}
```

With **older Java** versions:

```
static <T> boolean isValidEnum(String value, T enumClass ){
    for (Object v : ((Class) enumClass).getEnumConstants()){
        if (v.toString().equals(value)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for this, you can also use that in case you don't want to implement it.

[EnumUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html) of `org.apache.commons.lang3`

```
EnumUtils.isValidEnum(WeekDays.class, "TUESDAY")
```

Comment: `isValidEnum` also does the same thing internally what i am trying to do, interest was to understand the _under the hood_ thing!

Comment: @NoobEditor Yes I undestand, I just want let you know about the library.